# C# Wait for user input then continue with code

Tags: c#, powershell

I only have a basic understanding of the C# language but I am troubled, my program uses Powershell to perform tasks.

My specific problem is I am unable to attach an another event handler which can listen for a key press after the user has clicked a button, I'll explain.

1. User clicks button
2. Network trace begins using powershell (a user controls when to stop the trace)
3. My temp solution is to display a messagebox, when this is closed..
4. Stop the network trace

Is there anyway I can replace my message box where a user can press space to stop the trace?

Thankyou for your time and help in advance.

```
public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

///////////

ps.AddScript("netsh trace start persistent=yes capture=yes tracefile=" + progpath + @"\nettrace.etl");

ps.Invoke();

MessageBox.Show("Press OK to stop the trace");

ps.AddScript("netsh trace stop");

/////////

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by an Andy Lanng over at code project; 
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/892139/Csharp-Wait-for-user-input-then-continue-with-code

if this is a winforms application (the "MessageBox.Show" says that it is) then hitting space will trigger an event depending on which control has focus.
Hide   Copy Code

```
private void form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == ' ')
       ps.AddScript("netsh trace stop");
}
```

The problem is that you have stated that you cannot accept new events. I imagine that this is because the button3_Click event continues to run for some time, blocking other events.

I suggest you look at Threading and Async methods. Here one way (not fully tested)

```
    private PowerShell ps = new PowerShell { };
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        backgroundWorker.DoWork +=backgroundWorker_DoWork;

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ps.AddScript("netsh trace start persistent=yes capture=yes tracefile=" + progpath + @"\nettrace.etl");

        ps.Invoke();
    }
    private void form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == ' ')
            ps.AddScript("netsh trace stop");
    }
```

You will need to make a few changes for this to work such as adjusting if statements and where ps is declared.

Answer (score 1):

Could you have the button act as a toggle? Something like:

```
private static bool tracing = false;

public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tracing)
    {
        ps.AddScript("netsh trace stop");
        button3.Text = "Begin trace";
        ps.Invoke();
    }
    else
    {
        ps.AddScript("netsh trace start persistent=yes capture=yes tracefile=" + 
            progpath + @"\nettrace.etl");
        button3.Text = "Stop trace";
    }     

    tracing = !tracing;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rufus, 

Thats certainly an approach I hadn't considered and does indeed do the job! 

Thankyou for your assistance :)

Comment: Hi Rufus, I've unmarked your answer. I would like to go with my original plan! sorry.